# google maps api MarkerWithLabel position

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm creating new google maps marker.

```
   //displays[0].Latitude = -22.626111
   //displays[0].Longitude = -43.227489
  var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                            position: new google.maps.LatLng(displays[0].Latitude, displays[0].Longitude),
                            map: map,
                            labelContent: 1,
                            labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(6, 35),
                            labelClass: "map-label",
                            icon: pinSymbol(displays[0].Status)
                        });
```

And then getting position of marker

```
//marker.position.lng()
//-43.22748899999999
//marker.position.lat()
//-22.626111
```

Why its not equal?And how i can handle this?

Comment: Floating point numbers behave that way.

Answer (score 0):

You may handle this way:

```
  var latUrl = parseFloat(marker.position.toUrlValue().split(',', 2)[0]);
  var lngUrl = parseFloat(marker.position.toUrlValue().split(',', 2)[1]);
```

Hope it helps!